# How to find The Roots of Orthogonal polynomial equation

Tags: linear-algebra

> $P(z)$, with roots $z_j$'s for $0\leq j\leq a-1$.
>
> $$P(z)=z^a+c_{a-1}z^{a-1}+\ldots+c_1z+c_0.$$

I want to find the Roots of orthogonal polynomial equation but I don't know which method should I used.

Comment: What methods have your tried?

Comment: sir i am confused to which method i should used. so i use this platform to know i upload the picture